# Is it possible to order "first n" records randomly with only one SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

Is there a way to do this without two selects ?

Original query

```
SELECT name,view_count  
FROM `ex`.`item` 
where status='available' order by view_count asc 
limit 40;
```

To display randomly

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT name,view_count  
      FROM `ex`.`item` 
      where status='available' 
      order by view_count asc 
      limit 40 ) AS temp 
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Can this be done without a second select?

Comment: I don't think there's any better way that your second `SELECT`. Why do you think that's a problem?

Comment: @Barmar I don't, I was just curious to see if there are any alternatives and if yes how :)

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to read all the results of the first query into an array in the client application, and then shuffle that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/330f8/2

```
SELECT name, view_count 
FROM `ex`.`item` 
where status='available' 
order by rand(), view_count asc limit 40;
```